# No matching function for call

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member

I have a `.h` file containing

```
template <typename DataType>
class BST
{
private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
         //variables
    }
public:
    BinaryNode *root;

    int contains(const DataType &x, BinaryNode *&t) const;
}
```

I'm trying to call `contains` from:

```
void SequenceMap::merge(BST<SequenceMap> theMap)
{
    theMap.contains(this, theMap.root);
}
```

The implementation of `contains` is

```
template <typename DataType>int BST<DataType>::contains(const DataType &x, BST<DataType>::BinaryNode *&t) const
{
 //some stuff
}
```

I'm having the issue that it's saying: `no matching function call to BST<SequenceMap>::contains(SequenceMap* const, BST<SequenceMap>::BinaryNode*&)` at `theMap.contains(this,theMap.root)`

I'm not sure what part of this is wrong as `this` is a variable of `Datatype` `SequenceMap` and `theMap.root` is a `BinaryNode`. I have tried changing it to `*theMap.root` but that does not help.

Comment: `BST<SequenceMap>` Where's you template declaration for `BST`?? Are you actually missing **`template <typename T>`** `class BST { // ...`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually jaba10 just added code highlighting and capitalized something. I was the one who added the template declaration above BST as seen in revision 2.

Comment: it is not very nice to have private type used inside public method interface...

Comment: Well, then you clarified well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function calls for x by reference, not by pointer. You probably want:

```
theMap.contains(*this, theMap.root);
```